# Getting "Uncaught (inPromise) TypeError: ... sort is not a function" while trying to sort json data that is coming from the API by date attribute

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am trying to sort json data that is coming from the API by date attribute. However it gives me the following error. Please help me.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
        async function callAwsLambdaFunction() {
            fetch( 'URL',  {
                method: 'GET'
              })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((response) => {
                var json_obj = JSON.stringify(response.body);
                
                json_obj_sorted = json_obj.sort(function(a, b) {
                    var dateA = new Date(a.in_time), dateB = new Date(b.in_time);
                    return dateA - dateB;
                });

                console.log(json_obj_sorted);
                document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = json_obj_sorted;
            });
        }
    </script>   
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This is only a test, nothing else.</p>
        <p>Click below button to call API gateway and display result below!</p>
        <p><div id="myDiv"></div></p>
        <button onclick="callAwsLambdaFunction()">Click me!</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried also Object.entries but i keep getting following error in my console:
[image]

Comment: JSON.stringify returns a string, and strings don't have a sort method. What's the goal with stringifying it?

Comment: This `var json_obj = JSON.stringify(response.body);` is likely wrong as you want the parsed Javascript object, not a stringified version of it.  Change that to: `var json_obj = response.body;` and then do a `console.log(typeof json_obj, json_obj)` to see exactly what you have.

Comment: In addition, you should have a `.catch()` handler at the end of your promise chain so you can handle any error.

Comment: Thank you very much guys. Yes you were right json.stringify was returning to me a string. As soon as i substituted it with the var json_obj = response.body; It returned me a normal array. And the sorting worked. The reason why I was using stringify because if i don't use it was returning me [object Object].